# Store values in multidimensional array from BufferedReader

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, bufferedreader

I have an assignment for a car rental system which requires the program to read the from a CSV file, which contains each car and its specifications.

I will need to store the values into an array, as I will need to count how many cars are left after one is hired, as well as calculate the cost which is listed for each car.

```
1,Mazda CX-9,7,Automatic,Premium,150
2,VW Golf,5,Automatic,Standard,59
3,Toyota Corolla,5,Automatic ,Premium,55
4,VW Tiguan,7,Automatic,Premium,110
5,Ford Falcon,5,Manual,Standard,60
```

So far I've only been able to use `line.split(",")` to assign each column into a 1 dimensions array, which would output each number in index [0], each make in index[1], etc.

If I try `line.split("\n")` it assigns the whole file as is in index[0].

Please let me know what the best way to go about this would be.

I have been able to output the cars as I'd like to in code that I have not included here. The main problem is how to store the values appropriately.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String path = "carlist.csv";
    String line = "";
    long lines = 0;

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        lines++;
        String[] menu = line.split(",");
        System.out.println(menu[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting by `comma`, is the right way, you just need to store the the array returned from the `split` function into an ArrayList or an array of Strings array, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String path = "carlist.csv";
    String line = "";
    long lines = 0;
    
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();   
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        lines++;
        list.add(line.split(","));     
        System.out.println(menu[0]);

    }
}
```

Or like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String path = "carlist.csv";
    String line = "";
    long lines = 0;
    
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    String[][] cars = new String[100][6];  
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        cars[lines++] = line.split(",");     
        System.out.println(menu[0]);

    }
}
```

Here, I have taken 100 as the maximum number of records that will be in a CSV file, and 6 is the maximum length of the array, that will be obtained after splitting by comma. Both of these can be modified according to your use-case. Now, you can get any car and its specific elements like this `cars[0][3]`, or like this list.get(0)[3], depending on which implementation you use.

Comment: @xorian If you're allowed to then you might want to look into CSV parser libraries that can parse CSV files and return instances of a model class. Or at the very least do something similar yourself (i.e. create a `RentalCar` class with the necessary attributes and create instances as you parse the CSV file; that way you deal with a `List<RentalCar>` which can be much more readable).